# Bash, compare files. Removing values from file A that exist in File B

Tags: arrays, bash, while-loop

Greetings,

I have one file - more or less a greylisting file.  I need to compare the 40 to 50 values in it against a whitelisting file - and remove any values from the greylist that exists in the whitelist file.

Right now I'm taking each greylist value and comparing it against each value in the whitelisting file (which has 1 - 2 thousand values) and removing it from the greylisting if I find a match.  Then looping onto the next greylist value.

Seems horribly inefficient - but i'm not sure where to start to do what I'm looking for.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `grep -f` for this.

```
grep -F -v -f whitelist.txt greylist.txt
```

The values from `greylist.txt` that are not in `whitelist.txt` are then on stdout, you could redirect that to a file if you need to.

The options of grep do the following:

- `-F`: Interpret  PATTERN  as  a  list  of  fixed strings. (i.e. do not use regexes)
- `-v`: Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
- `-f`: Obtain  patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.

See [man grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep)

Answer (score 1):

Can you sort either file? Doing so would allow you to early-exit on your searches, speeding things up a lot - especially if you can sort both, in which case you'd only have to traverse each file once (since you just move ahead in whichever file is currently at a lower value).

Comment: Thank you Amber, that won't help in this case - but there is someplace else I can use it.